# Study the convergence of this sequence of functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

I have the following sequence of function:
$$f_n(\lambda)=\bigg[\alpha-i\bigg(\lambda+\frac{1}{n}\bigg)\bigg]^{-1}-\bigg[\alpha-i\lambda\bigg]^{-1},\,\,\,\alpha\neq 0$$
and I have to study its convergence in $(0,+\infty)$.
For pointwise convergence I see that for fixed $\lambda>0$
$$\lim_n f_n(\lambda)=0$$. What can a say about uniform convergence?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\alpha\neq 0$ is real. Note that
\begin{eqnarray*}
|f_n(\lambda)|&=&\left|\frac{i}{n}\frac{1}{(\alpha-i\lambda)(\alpha-i(\lambda+\frac{1}{n})}\right|\\
&=&\frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{(\alpha^2+\lambda^2)(\alpha^2+(\lambda+\frac{1}{n})^2)}}\\
&=&\le \frac{1}{\alpha^2n}
\end{eqnarray*}
and hence $f_n(\lambda)\to 0$ uniformly as $n\to\infty$. For complex $\alpha$, you can discuss similarly.